# How to set text for different location in pass when pushing on iPod or iPhone screen

Tags: ios, rest, passbook

I just create some passes and add some location, but I don't know to set text for different location. How to do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply need to add a different `relevantText` key to each location entry in your `pass.json`.

```
"locations": [{
        "latitude": 22.284664905736,
        "longitude": 114.15818423018,
        "relevantText": "Visit our ifc branch"
    }, {
        "latitude": 22.2864734223,
        "longitude": 114.16105383063,
        "relevantText": "Come see us at Star Ferry"
    }, {
        "latitude": 22.282069510469,
        "longitude": 114.15340739122,
        "relevantText": "We're here in Shelly St"
    }, {
        "latitude": 22.280349497127,
        "longitude": 114.17643496924,
        "relevantText": "Find us in Brim 28"
    }],
```

Comment: before I share to iPod by app

Comment: Same way you would share with an iPhone - put your .pkpass bundle on a server and serve with a mime type of `application/vnd.apple.pkpass`

Answer (score 0):

One small point to add to PassKit's answer - you can fit approx. 23 characters of text in your relevantText string - any other characters won't fit on the lock-screen and get cut off ..

Comment: Thanks ! And do you have link to confirm that maximum characters is 23 or you tested already ?  So what to add to those characters in order have a new line of string on lock screen  ?

Comment: I tested it myself to find the maximum number of characters. I don't think it's possible to have two lines on the lock screen. Even if you configure for two locations very close together, only one message will be displayed per Pass (whichever is triggered first).

Comment: Thanks anyway ! Then, I use only 1 line ! :D